# How to compare the each value present in array by using .filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

This is my code to filter out the record

```
 for (var k = 0; k < $scope.hockeyPlayersId.length; k++) {
     var val = $scope.hockeyPlayersId[k];
     $scope.filterhockeyPlayers = $scope.Players.filter(function (obj, index) {
         var returnVal = true;
         if (val) {
             if (obj.PlayersId == val)
                 return 1
             else
                 return 0;
         }

         return returnVal;
     });//End of filter function ;
 }
```

val contains all the Ids of the player which play hockey. I am comparing the each `PlayersId` of obj with val but `$scope.filterhockeyPlayers` returns wrong value if `$scope.hockeyPlayersId = ['22','12','21']` then returns the players which contains only 21 id. I want player of 22 and 12 also. `$scope.filterhockeyPlayers` value is lost after each for loop.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the input and expected output arrays.

Comment: @Randy : The value of $scope.filterhockeyPlayers getting erased after each for loop i.e  for k = 0 I have two similar player but when k become 1 that two value getting erased

Comment: Besides the logic errors in your code, it should be clear to you that this assignment: `$scope.filterhockeyPlayers =` is resulting in your loss of data. But since you are unwilling to share the input data it is impossible to tell what else is occurring.

Comment: Can you provide the `$scope` what is it and what are its properties/methods. also why do you have `returnVal` in the filter function just return true instead it is not like you are changing it ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

1. You're overriding `$scope.filterhockeyPlayers` at each iteration of the `for` loop, so only the results of the last item of `$scope.hockeyPlayersId` will be used, the rest are omitted.
2. `returnVal` is totally useless. Either `1` or `0` will be returned due to `if-else`.

Now, to fix this you'll have to change the code so that `filter` is the outermost. And for each object in `$scope.Players` just check if the id of that object is included in `$scope.hockeyPlayersId` by using `Array#indexOf` or `Array#includes`:

```
 $scope.filterhockeyPlayers = $scope.Players.filter(function (obj) {   // filter objects from $scope.Players
     return $scope.hockeyPlayersId.includes(obj.PlayersId);            // where the id is included in $scope.hockeyPlayersId
 });
```

Which is the same as using a `for` loop like so:

```
$scope.filterhockeyPlayers = $scope.Players.filter(function (obj) {
     for (var k = 0; k < $scope.hockeyPlayersId.length; k++) {
         if(obj.PlayersId == $scope.hockeyPlayersId[k]) {
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 });
```

I hope it makes sense ;-)

Comment: : Thanx. Value is not getting lost after each for loop.Thanks a lot